# Connection to mysql timed out

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have upgraded my version of [AppServ](http://www.appservnetwork.com/) to the 2.6.0. I was running a previous version and everything worked fine. But now php can't connect to MySQL. The page takes a lot of time to load, and when it does, an error comes saying (translated with Google):

`An error occurred during the connection attempt because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or there was an error in the connection established because connected host has failed to respond.`

All php pages that don't require MySQL work perfect.

I am using Windows 7. AppServ installed these versions of:

- Apache **2.2.8**
- PHP **6.0.0-dev**
- MySQL **6.0.4-alpha**

**EDIT:**

doing a phpinfo I could read this line: `Client API version: mysqlnd 5.0.4-dev`. All I can guess from that is that the mysql version is not the one I am using (6.0.4). How could I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you need to use an alpha version of MySQL, unless you know exactly what you are doing. 
I don't know AppServ, but with Wamp you can install separately a different version of MySQL. Try to install a stable version of MySQL (5.5.X for example) or install a previous version of AppServ.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have installed Wamp and everything works fine! And I like this more than appserv.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your configuration is pointing to a different MySQL version. I know this video is about creating a new database, but perhaps you can use it to check and correct your configuration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QWqL-2qq0Jo